# Using valgrind in bash to generate outputs from multiple C files

Tags: bash, valgrind

I am attempting to generate a valgrind output to a file for multiple C files within a loop, some of which may segfault.

```bash
while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; do 
    mkdir "$p"
    cd "$p"
    if ! cp -rL /class/cs2050/submissions/A/"$1"/"$p/" "$p" ; then
        echo "$p" >> $missing # If no valid submisision, add them to the (temporary) invalid list so we can go look for them (maybe they submitted late?)
        echo "DID NOT SUBMIT A LAB WITHIN WINDOW"
    else
        cp $source_header "$p"
        cp $source_main "$p"
        compile "$p"/"$1"main.c  "$p"/"$1".c -o "main"
        touch valgrind.txt
        valgrind --log-file="valgrind.txt" ./main
    fi
    cd ..
done < "$file"
```

Is it possible to "ignore" segfaults from each program and continue going through each file?

Comment: An error in the program shouldn't stop the loop. Did you do something silly like `set -e`?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as "not reproducible". Glad you solved you problem.

Comment: People who use [set -e](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) should be aware of the consequences.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.